# how to change the area for background color around link on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have set background color on hover, but it is showing on link as in pic: [image: bg color on hover] .

How can I properly align the background color around the link? I am using height and width, but it is changing position of link instead background color.

CSS for link:

```
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {  
   color : #44546a ;  
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align : middle ;
   margin-top : 20px ;
   padding-bottom : 0px;
   font-weight : bold ;               
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li:hover > a {
   background-color : #00a0b7 ;
   color :    white   ;
   height : ?????? ;
   width  : ??????? ;
}
```

Comment: There's obviously something wrong with your `paddings/margins`. Please post all your `navbar css code` so we see where you wrong

Comment: Check this out [https://css-tricks.com/keep-margins-out-of-link-lists/](https://css-tricks.com/keep-margins-out-of-link-lists/)

Answer (score 1):

With bootstrap you can just do that

```
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {  
color : #44546a ;  
display: inline-block;
vertical-align : middle ;
font-weight : bold ;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li:hover > a{
background-color : #00a0b7 ;
color :    white   ;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/SeniorFront/DTcHh/30060/

Answer (score 1):

try this with the content you needed

```css
.navbar ul li {  
color : #44546a ;  
display: inline-block;
font-weight : bold ;
}
.navbar ul li a{
padding:5px;
}
.navbar ul li::after{
content:'|';
}

.navbar ul li a:hover{
background-color:#0095ff;
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="navbar">
<ul>
<li><a>Home</a></li>
<li><a>Company</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**linkClass {color:red;}
linkClass:hover{color:blue;}**

> `<a href='' class='linkClass'>Sample link</a>`